# What if I delete the contents of my home folder?

Tags: debian

I have a Debian machine with Gnome 3 that I use as a server, usually from the command line. I was wondering what will happen if I delete all contents of folder `/home/USER/` except for the following ones:

- .bashrc
- .profile
- .ssh/

And then restart the machine. I assume that I will still be able to access the machine from the command line but what about the GUI? Will everything be reseted to default or it will fail to load?

Comment: Nothing so bad. You can try that if you want. [If still not sure...](https://wiki.debian.org/home_directory)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would still be able to log in normally, and necessary files (that you deleted, such as GUI settings, program settings) would be recreated as needed (with default settings), the same way they would in case you create a new user account and first log in. You would lose customizations that you did by hand to certain programs and configuration files (if any), but that would be pretty much it.

If you want, you could "test drive" this before actually deleting the files, by creating a new user account and logging in using this new credentials - if that logs in normally, so will your regular account. Out of abundance of caution, it is always advisable to copy the deleted files to a backup, just in case.